# How to automatically derive function arguments with type and value?

Tags: gcc, g++

I've seen codes doing things like this at the beginning of each function: print the function name, and each argument name and value, to help logging and debugging purposes. I wonder if there is anyway to automate this. For example, in the following code is it possible to replace `(... "%d, %d", x, y)` with some macro or other tool? Thanks a lot.

```
void foo(int x, int y)
{
    trace(__FUNCTION__, "%d, %d", x, y);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had there been some `__args__` variable/macro, this would probably have been possible. However, there is no such a thing in the C or C++ standard, whichever norm you chose. The only thing you could do here to save some typing is to get rid of `__FUNCTION__` by defining a macro like this one (C99+ or C++11+):

```
#define TRACE(fmt, ...) trace(__FUNCTION__, fmt, __VA_ARGS__);
```

Unfortunately, no trick will allow you to get the arguments name and value without feeding them one by one to `trace` or `TRACE`, at least not in any existing C or C++ standard. There might be some reflection features to come in C++ one day, but you will at least have to wait for a few more years.